# Why do I get subquery error with SqlDependency

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

My DB Admin had to make some permission/ownership changes yesterday. Previous my SqlDependency code had been working well.

But now there is what I believe is a credentials issue (I believe this because I saw one small note after a long web search).

I am connecting successfully to MS SQL using this connection string:

```
        connectionString = @"user id=billybob;" +
                                    @"password=bigsecret;" +
                                   "server=11.2.133.8;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=no;" +
                                   "database=MYDB; " +
                                   "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" +
                                   "connection timeout=30";
```

Then I try to start a SqlDependency with:

```
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, null);
```

But I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled   HResult=-2146232060
>   Message=Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted
>   when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is
>   used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

What might be the issue?

Fuller trace for Kilanny:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.SqlConnectionContainer.CreateQueueAndService(Boolean
>   restart)    at
>   SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.SqlConnectionContainer..ctor(SqlConnectionContainerHashHelper
>   hashHelper, String appDomainKey, Boolean useDefaults)    at
>   SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.Start(String connectionString, String&
>   server, DbConnectionPoolIdentity& identity, String& user, String&
>   database, String& queueService, String appDomainKey,
>   SqlDependencyPerAppDomainDispatcher dispatcher, Boolean&
>   errorOccurred, Boolean& appDomainStart, Boolean useDefaults)    at
>   SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.StartWithDefault(String
>   connectionString, String& server, DbConnectionPoolIdentity& identity,
>   String& user, String& database, String& service, String appDomainKey,
>   SqlDependencyPerAppDomainDispatcher dispatcher, Boolean&
>   errorOccurred, Boolean& appDomainStart)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(String connectionString,
>   String queue, Boolean useDefaults)

This is the code where is it called:

PLease note error occurs BEFORE query is created!

```
public void InitialiseDependency(Action onDependencyMethod)
{
    this.onDependencyMethod = onDependencyMethod;
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, null); //<<<< ERROR ON THIS LINE

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [dbo].[tbls] WHERE [Status] = 'NEW'",
            conn))
    {

        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);


        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not related to connection string you are showing. But related to the query you execute, which you didn't show.

Comment: @Kilanny. I do NOT believe it is to do with the Query BECAUSE - I have made NO changes to it in months. The only thing that has changed is the Permissions on the DB and tables.

Comment: `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` This error is related to some query. Maybe the problem wasn't arise for some months, but it finally raised when suitable conditions come. You should contact the developer of app. Please show the entire stacktrace.

Comment: @Kilanny. I have added the trace as your requested BUT please note error happens BEFORE the query is created!

Comment: Ok. To help you find the problem, first, restore your old credentials that were working. Second, run sql server profiler and notice the command executed when the line  `SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, null);` executed. Third, put that query for us.

Comment: @Kilanny. That's the point. I don't know the old credentials...

Comment: Ask your DB Admin who changed it.

Comment: @Kilanny. He is unable to help. The question really is - what credentials DO I NEED to call SqlDependency.Start

Answer (score 0):

Eventually we deleted and recreated user "billybob". As soon as we did that the error went away....